# Quickest way to load and parse large files?

Tags: c#, opentk

I'm trying to make an obj loader in OpenTK, and it works, however takes ages to load obj files. Here's what I have:

```
public async void LoadObj()
{
    vertices = new List<Vector3>();
    normals = new List<Vector3>();
    texCoords = new List<Vector2>();
    objVerticesIndexDictionary = new Dictionary<ObjVertex, int>();
    objVertices = new List<ObjVertex>();
    triangles = new List<ObjTriangle>();
    quads = new List<ObjQuad>();

    string result = "";
    using (StreamReader fileRead = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        result = fileRead.ReadToEnd();
        fileRead.Close();
    }
    string[] resultLines = result.Split('\n');
    foreach (string line in resultLines)
    {
        Console.Write("...");
        string[] parameters = line.Split(' ');
        switch (parameters[0])
        {
            case "p": // Point
                break;

            case "v": // Vertex
                float x = float.Parse(parameters[1]);
                float y = float.Parse(parameters[2]);
                float z = float.Parse(parameters[3]);
                vertices.Add(new Vector3(x, y, z));
                break;

            case "vt": // TexCoord
                float u = float.Parse(parameters[1]);
                float v = float.Parse(parameters[2]);
                texCoords.Add(new Vector2(u, v));
                break;

            case "vn": // Normal
                float nx = float.Parse(parameters[1]);
                float ny = float.Parse(parameters[2]);
                float nz = float.Parse(parameters[3]);
                normals.Add(new Vector3(nx, ny, nz));
                break;

            case "f":
                switch (parameters.Length)
                {
                    case 4:
                        ObjTriangle objTriangle = new ObjTriangle();
                        objTriangle.Index0 = ParseFaceParameter(parameters[1]);
                        objTriangle.Index1 = ParseFaceParameter(parameters[2]);
                        objTriangle.Index2 = ParseFaceParameter(parameters[3]);
                        triangles.Add(objTriangle);
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        ObjQuad objQuad = new ObjQuad();
                        objQuad.Index0 = ParseFaceParameter(parameters[1]);
                        objQuad.Index1 = ParseFaceParameter(parameters[2]);
                        objQuad.Index2 = ParseFaceParameter(parameters[3]);
                        objQuad.Index3 = ParseFaceParameter(parameters[4]);
                        quads.Add(objQuad);
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, `LoadObj()` will read a specified obj file and run a switch for each line. Not sure how efficient this system is, I am still learning C#. Is there a faster and more efficient way to load an obj file?? Thanks.

Comment: How large are these OBJ files? Or, a better question, how many lines do they contain?

Comment: Have you worked out *what* takes the time? Is it loading the file, splitting it into lines, or parsing each line? Also, please take some time to format your code when you post - it's really hard to read without any indentation.

Comment: I typically have loading issues with basically all obj files. Each vertex is in a new line, same with faces. For example, a perfect cube would have 8 vertices and 6 faces, so all together, 14 lines). Also, sorry about the format. I had to post this on mobile and the indentations got messed up. I'm assuming the part that takes the most time is when each line is being parsed through the main switch.

Comment: You need to run your code in a profiler to determine what is taking time. For all we know, there could be something crazy going on in your `ParseFaceParameter` method but we don't see the source for it. If you have VS Premium or higher there is a built in profiler (Analyze -> Performance and Diagnostics). Otherwise, have a look at SlimTune.

Comment: I don't think the problem is within ParseFaceParameter -- all it does is turn a face into a quad or triangle. I'm pretty sure it's just the fact that the current way I'm loading it is that it loops for every line -- for a hipoly model, it can easily exceed 5000 lines. I need to find a way to load this more efficiently.